# Is there any way to make commas(,) escapable in a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a `String str = "13-005B,162-,0000-"`. I have a function named `outputUtill` which need a input in format:-  `="(string1 value)",="(string2 value)",="(string3 value)"`. The `outputUtill` function splits the input string based on `","` as delimiter. Is there any way so I can make the commas(,) escapable in `String str` so that when it becomes of format:-  `="13-005B,162-,0000-"` and passes to `outputUtill function` it does not get split into three substring

1. 13-005B
2. 162-
3. 0000-

For example, we pass

```
="370143030",="SPRING TOWNSHIP CENTRE",="1869 ZION ROAD BELLEFONTE PA 16823",="8143551",="02",="13-005B,162-,0000-",
```

to the outputUtill function. We want output as

```
370143030
SPRING TOWNSHIP CENTRE
1869 ZION ROAD BELLEFONTE PA 16823
8143551
02
13-005B,162-,0000-
```

Comment: You could replace all the commas with another character or sequence

Comment: Suppose  we pass 
="370143030",="SPRING TOWNSHIP CENTRE",="1869 ZION ROAD BELLEFONTE PA 16823",="8143551",="02",="13-005B,162-,0000-", 
to the outputUtill function. We want output as

370143030
SPRING TOWNSHIP CENTRE
1869 ZION ROAD BELLEFONTE PA 16823
8143551
02
13-005B,162-,0000-

Comment: I don't get what should be the result, this question is very confusing.
You have "13-005B,162-,0000-" in input, then you need the same string without commas? and should be one string and not 3 separated strings?

Comment: That's not a valid String

Comment: check the question once again. I have tried to make it more readable.

Comment: as @AdriaanKoster said, you can't pass such a string, it's not even a string, try to use lists instead.

Comment: Isn't the entire point of those `="..."` to enclose single values? If so, the problem is not that you need to escape things, it means that you need to fix however you're parsing things right now, because I think it should already work the way you want, and if it doesn't that would be a bug. In other words, your code should not just split on `,`, it needs to actually **parse** the row to distinguish quoted values and separators.

Comment: Are you in control of implementation of the `outputUtill` function ?

Right of the bat the best solution seems to use a different separator. A kind of a separator that you would not encounter within the token body ... 

Otherwise, you could replace commas with something like "<comma>" string in the input before the split, and then replace the "<comma>" string back to "," after the split is done.

Comment: The main input and output is a csv file. The csv input gets processed and then formatted into the required format and passed on to `outputUtill` function. That is a reason for which I cannot replace "," with "<comma>" or any other delimiter.

Comment: Maybe take a look at OpenCSV (https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

outputUtil could split on the sequence ",=" and trim the leading and ending =" and ",

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "=\"370143030\",=\"SPRING TOWNSHIP CENTRE\",=\"1869 ZION ROAD BELLEFONTE PA 16823\",=\"8143551\",=\"02\",=\"13-005B,162-,0000-\", ";
    String sep = "\",=\"";

    String[] output = input.substring(2, input.length() - 3).split(sep);
    Arrays.stream(output).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
}
```

Output:

```
370143030
SPRING TOWNSHIP CENTRE
1869 ZION ROAD BELLEFONTE PA 16823
8143551
02
13-005B,162-,0000-
```